# How to read a iqy file result table with javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, sharepoint, internet-explorer-8

so I have an IQY file (Internet Query file), it's found locally on my computer. This file when opened in excel will show me a table of a SharePoint list. I would like to use JavaScript, in IE browser (I can use ActiveXObject if needed) to search the resulted table for a value.

I already know how to search in excel, So that's not the problem. How can I turn this IQY file into an temp excel sheet with JavaScript? If it's not possible, is there a way to read from the table using the IQY file without using excel?

I hope my question is understandable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a way to overcome this problem. In the file data there's an href, that when opened by a browser will display the data in excel format. So I've used this data to get the information I needed.